# java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException when tranquility index data to druid

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, druid

I am trying tranquility with Druid 0.11 and Kafka. When tranquility receive new data it throw the following exception:

```
2018-01-12 18:27:34,010 [Curator-ServiceCache-0] INFO  c.m.c.s.net.finagle.DiscoResolver - Updating instances for service[firehose:druid:overlord:flow-018-0000-0000] to Set(ServiceInstance{name='firehose:druid:overlord:flow-018-0000-0000', id='ea85b248-0c53-4ec1-94a6-517525f72e31', address='druid-md-deployment-7877777bf7-tmmvh.druid-md-hs.default.svc.cluster.local', port=8100, sslPort=-1, payload=null, registrationTimeUTC=1515781653895, serviceType=DYNAMIC, uriSpec=null})
Jan 12, 2018 6:27:37 PM com.twitter.finagle.netty3.channel.ChannelStatsHandler exceptionCaught
WARNING: ChannelStatsHandler caught an exception
java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:101)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:622)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.connect(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:779)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.connectRequested(SimpleChannelHandler.java:306)
```

The worker was created by middle Manager:

```
2018-01-12T18:27:25,704 INFO [WorkerTaskMonitor] io.druid.indexing.worker.WorkerTaskMonitor - Submitting runnable for task[index_realtime_flow_2018-01-12T18:00:00.000Z_0_0]
2018-01-12T18:27:25,719 INFO [WorkerTaskMonitor] io.druid.indexing.worker.WorkerTaskMonitor - Affirmative. Running task [index_realtime_flow_2018-01-12T18:00:00.000Z_0_0]
```

And tranquility talk with overlord fine... I think by the following logs:

```
2018-01-12T18:27:25,268 INFO [qtp271944754-62] io.druid.indexing.overlord.TaskLockbox - Adding task[index_realtime_flow_2018-01-12T18:00:00.000Z_0_0] to activeTasks
2018-01-12T18:27:25,272 INFO [TaskQueue-Manager] io.druid.indexing.overlord.TaskQueue - Asking taskRunner to run: index_realtime_flow_2018-01-12T18:00:00.000Z_0_0
2018-01-12T18:27:25,272 INFO [TaskQueue-Manager] io.druid.indexing.overlord.RemoteTaskRunner - Added pending task index_realtime_flow_2018-01-12T18:00:00.000Z_0_0
2018-01-12T18:27:25,279 INFO [rtr-pending-tasks-runner-0] io.druid.indexing.overlord.RemoteTaskRunner - No worker selection strategy set. Using default of [EqualDistributionWorkerSelectStrategy]
2018-01-12T18:27:25,294 INFO [rtr-pending-tasks-runner-0] io.druid.indexing.overlord.RemoteTaskRunner - Coordinator asking Worker[druid-md-deployment-7877777bf7-tmmvh.druid-md-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:8091] to add task[index_realtime_flow_2018-01-12T18:00:00.000Z_0_0]
2018-01-12T18:27:25,334 INFO [rtr-pending-tasks-runner-0] io.druid.indexing.overlord.RemoteTaskRunner - Task index_realtime_flow_2018-01-12T18:00:00.000Z_0_0 switched from pending to running (on [druid-md-deployment-7877777bf7-tmmvh.druid-md-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:8091])
2018-01-12T18:27:25,336 INFO [rtr-pending-tasks-runner-0] io.druid.indexing.overlord.TaskRunnerUtils - Task [index_realtime_flow_2018-01-12T18:00:00.000Z_0_0] status changed to [RUNNING].
2018-01-12T18:27:25,747 INFO [Curator-PathChildrenCache-1] io.druid.indexing.overlord.RemoteTaskRunner - Worker[druid-md-deployment-7877777bf7-tmmvh.druid-md-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:8091] wrote RUNNING status for task [index_realtime_flow_2018-01-12T18:00:00.000Z_0_0] on [TaskLocation{host='null', port=-1, tlsPort=-1}]
2018-01-12T18:27:25,829 INFO [Curator-PathChildrenCache-1] io.druid.indexing.overlord.RemoteTaskRunner - Worker[druid-md-deployment-7877777bf7-tmmvh.druid-md-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:8091] wrote RUNNING status for task [index_realtime_flow_2018-01-12T18:00:00.000Z_0_0] on [TaskLocation{host='druid-md-deployment-7877777bf7-tmmvh.druid-md-hs.default.svc.cluster.local', port=8100, tlsPort=-1}]
2018-01-12T18:27:25,829 INFO [Curator-PathChildrenCache-1] io.druid.indexing.overlord.TaskRunnerUtils - Task [index_realtime_flow_2018-01-12T18:00:00.000Z_0_0] location changed to [TaskLocation{host='druid-md-deployment-7877777bf7-tmmvh.druid-md-hs.default.svc.cluster.local', port=8100, tlsPort=-1}].
```

What's wrong? I tried a thousand things and nothing solves it ...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

[UnresolvedAddressException being hit by Druid broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840594/unresolvedaddressexception-being-hit-by-druid-broker)

You have to have all the druid cluster information set in you servers running tranquility.
It's because you only get DNS of you druid cluster from zookeeper, not the IP.
For example, on linux server, save you cluster information in /etc/hosts.

Comment: Exactly, the problem was I deploy over Kubernetes and the pods didn’t set its host to the Kubernetes DNS. I solved this with service ClusterIP: None and changing deploy by statefulset.